# using painteventargs in a c# form; how do I draw a larger image to the Graphics object (with scrollbars as well)?

Tags: c#, graphics, draw

I'm writing some data acquisition code.  As the app acquires data it draws a graph to a content pane.  Everything works perfectly right now for our data comprised of fixed length scans: the graph is just scaled to fit into the graphics object obtained from painteventargs.   We are now implementing a "free scan" that just grows in length as you collect data.  We would like to draw the graph, which is ever increasing in size, to the graphics object from painteventargs but once it grows larger than the graphics object an "out of memory" exception is generated.  Is there a way to grow the graphics object or simply replace it?  We want to be able to use the scroll bars to see all of the data.

Thanks for any help!

Here's a chunk of the code (Note: I understand why I'm getting the out of memory error -- the bitmap is too big.  This was just one attempt to do what I'm trying to do.  I'm asking the question because I'm stumped at the moment.):

```
    System.Drawing.Graphics G = e.Graphics;
    e.Graphics.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.White);                
    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(10000, 1000);
    Graphics h = Graphics.FromImage(bm);
    h.DrawLine(myPens[0], 0, 0, 1000, 10000);
    G.DrawImage(bm,0,0);
```

Comment: Post relevant code. Out of memory exception indicates you're doing something terribly wrong

Comment: Thanks, Sriram.  I understand why I'm getting the out of memory error -- I'm trying to draw an image that is too big to the graphics object that I obtain from painteventargs.  I just don't know how to get a canvas that is larger than my content pane so that it triggers the scrollbars.  I also want to be able to grow it as more data arrives!

Comment: you can trigger the scrollbar by setting AutoScrollMinSize to a size greater than your form has,oh and you might think of using another overload of the drawimage,like drawimage(image,rectangle),which rectangle will be size of the control,so every time you have new image it will be resized acordingly.

Comment: You're creating `Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(10000, 1000);` everytime but where you're disposing?

Answer (score 0):

What I'd recommend you is calculating average points and graph them instead of every single data point. This is also done by leading chart controls. To not to hide details from the user, you should implement a zooming function which takes only a specific interval of your data. As more as you zoom in the less the interval of time. And the more you Zoom in the more details you can show. Hope this strategy will help you further.

Comment: Thanks, Sam.  We already have that functionality implemented for our other scans.  What we want here is precisely what I describe: the ability to plot every data point and scroll along the data (almost like an old-fashioned graph written to a scroll of graph paper).